# Android Studio debugger taking too long to start/load

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I had recently intalled NDK and had worked on jni for some time. I am again now shifted to my normal Android work but now when I am applying a debugger, the debugger is taking too much time to load. It loads many so files and all which are required to debug native code/ jni related stuff. I want to disable this so that debugger knows that I do not wnt to debug any cpp files. I am using Android studio 2.2.2 and I have tried setting "Debug type" of debugger to "Java" from "Edit Configurations" but it did not helped me. It stills loads the LLDB server and related so files while stating debugger.

Any help would be really appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

run app first, then press the "attach debugger to android process" button, it will open a choose process dialog, set the debugger from 'auto' to 'java'.

[image: press this button]

Comment: awesome! quick Q: so why doesn't the regular debug button works as fast as this run and attach later ?

Comment: Wow, not a good design. This was usually automatic, so many months or even years without realizing I had to manually attach it.

Answer (score 16):

Its probably because you have introduced C++ native libraries in your App, to only debug java, click **Run** > **Edit Configurations** and then in the **debugger** tab, change **Debug Type** to **Java**

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug):

> Because different debugger tools are required to debug Java/Kotlin
>   code and C/C++ code, the Android Studio debugger allows you to select
>   which debugger type to use. By default, Android Studio decides which
>   debugger to use based on which languages it detects in your project
>   (with the Auto debugger type)
>
> The debug types available include the following:
>
> **Auto**
>
> automatically choose the best option for the code you are debugging.
>   For example, if you have any C or C++ code in your project, Android
>   Studio automatically uses the Dual debug type. Otherwise, Android
>   Studio uses the Java debug type.
>
> **Java**
>
> Select this debug type if you
>   want to debug only code written in Java or Kotlin—the Java debugger
>   ignores any breakpoints or watches you set in your native code.
>
> **Native** (available only with C/C++ code)
>
> Select this debug type if you want to
>   use only LLDB to debug your code. When using this debug type, the Java
>   debugger session view is not available. By default, LLDB inspects only
>   your native code and ignores breakpoints in your Java code. If you
>   want to also debug your Java code, you should switch to either the
>   Auto or Dual debug type.Select this debug type if you want Android Studio to

Answer (score 0):

1). Go to the debugger and select view breakpoints

2).Make sure the All Breakpoint is unchecked.

[image]