# The app freezes while debugging but if I just run the app everything works fine

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea

Can't debug an Android app. When I click on the Debug button, the app starts but it freezes at the first screen. This happens only when I debug the app, if I just run the app everything works fine. I tried to run the app first and then attach debugger to Android process but it did not help.

I can't figure out what the problem is. What can slow down debugging?
Tried all these solutions [stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio), [stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233281/android-studio-debugger-taking-too-long-to-start-load), [intellij-support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping)

The app has pretty big codebase. I can provide any additional info if needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you debugging with emulator or real device?

Comment: With real device

Comment: simply open an app with normal mode and then attach the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

In any terminal such as Termux,etc run this command after 5-6 minutes of every reboot/power on:
su -c "/system/bin/device_config put activity_manager max_phantom_processes 2147483647"

You shouldn't face this freezing issue then.

You can read more about this here:
https://gist.github.com/agnostic-apollo/dc7e47991c512755ff26bd2d31e72ca8

Comment: Is this definitely causing the issue of OP?